# VS2013 Javascript Debugging

Tags: visual-studio-2013

Does any one know how to enable in page JavaScript script tag debugging?

In vs2012 i can go to the page in visual studio which is running in the debugger and create a break point however in vs2013 i get "A breakpoint could not be inserted at this location"?

Thanks

Comment: What Browser you using? I can debug using IE - (v10)

Comment: @Jonathan D - did this ever find a resolution?  I'm a metoo!

Comment: no I haven't sorry only thing you can do is move the JavaScript to an external file.

Comment: For me, the breakpoints in `<script>` blocks was working, then stopped. I'm guessing there's a bug...

Answer (score 1):

try to keep your scripts in separate files and put the breakpoints in that files. I had the same problem but when I moved java scripts from my views to script files I was able to debug. It may not be a solution but at least you should be able to work.

Comment: yeah this is basicly what i ended up doing, i found if you do need to debug an inline put "debugger;" in the JavaScript and you can do it that way but its a bit of a pain.

Comment: I don't understand why MS change it this way it's co inconvenient some times. What I'm doing also is debugging with browser development tools, still not perfect but better this than nothing

Answer (score 0):

There was a known issue in Visual Studio 2013 that caused breakpoints to not work correctly inside script blocks.  A fix was made and is included in the recently released Visual Studio 2013 Update 2 RC, which you can install from http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42307.