# Javascript debugging in VS2013 not working properly

Tags: javascript, debugging, visual-studio-2013

There is a problem with VS 2013 and debugging JS code.
The problem is like when I try to debug a JS code in VS 2013 the debugger does not pause the code execution (which it should ideally) and let me debug. there is a workaround for this though which is run the code again the debugger will pause the code execution second time.

I usually don't load the solution I just open only the files (.js or .htm ) I need to debug and put the Debugger; in the code and run the page in the IE it invokes the JIT but previously in VS2010 it also pause he code execution in the line with Debugger;

But funny thing is it does so when i run the same code twice in the second time it hit the debugger; and pauses the code execution in the VS2013.

I did a little bit of googling after that i found that this is a known issue with VS 2103 and which has been fixed in Update 2.

[Unable to debug](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/807088/unable-to-debug-javascript-from-the-vs-2013-ide-unable-to-set-breakpoint)

[VS2013 Javascript Debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19706520/vs2013-javascript-debugging)

which all says the problem was fixed in the Update 2 but i have Update 4 installed in my system .

Is there any way to fix this. OR i am doing something wrong like any setting or something.

Comment: I am facing similar problem. My fix is to re-run the project and debug. One thing make sure your web project is selected as startup project. Cheers.

Comment: It not helping either

Comment: Found a possible work around 

writing debugger 2 times will break it at frist time.

like :-  debugger;debuger;